# How do I make an IRC Channel with password?

Tags: irc

How do I make a password protected IRC Channel?

I've looked at the documentation and everything. But I'm not sure how to make a channel in the first place.

Is there any documentation or a guide to doing so?

Answer (score 5):

If you're an op on that channel, you can use the following

```
/MODE #channel +k MyPrivateKey
```

In order to join the above protected channel, use

```
/JOIN #channel MyPrivateKey
```

Remember to change the word "channel" with your channel name and "MyPrivateKey" to your desired password.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts:
1. how to make a channel
2. how to make it password protected

The answer to the second part can be found in [Orel Eraki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46380032/1613005).

The answer to the first question is as follows if you want to use a client on your computer, otherwise use the server's web GUI (for example https://webchat.freenode.net/):

1. open your IRC client

   - If you don't know what to install, here is my list:

     - GUI (graphical user interface)

       - OSX: [LimeChat](http://limechat.net/mac/)
       - Linux: [HexChat](https://hexchat.github.io/)
       - windows: [HexChat](https://hexchat.github.io/)
     - TUI (Text-based User Interface)

       - irssi
2. Select a server and google it's port number

   - for example `chat.freenode.net` or `irc.europnet.org`
3. connect to the server

   - `/server chat.freenode.net`
4. Register your nickname on the server (most GUI clients do this automatically). for example freenode has a [guideline](http://freenode.net/kb/answer/registration):

   - `/msg NickServ REGISTER password youremail@example.com`
5. Start your own channel

   - `/join #YourChannelName`